# How to add annotations to MKMapView asynchronously?

Tags: iphone, ios, asynchronous, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a lot of annotations to be added to a mkmapview. When i add the annotations, the app freezes for a short period of time. I have understand that the main thread is the only thread allowed to add UI to view, if this is true, how to i make this operation not freeze the app?

```
// in viewdidLoad
for (NSManagedObject *object in requestResults) {
     CustomAnnotation *customAnnotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] init];
     customAnnotation.title = object.title;
     customAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([object.latitude doubleValue], [object.longitude doubleValue]);
     [_mapView addAnnotation:customAnnotation];
} 
} // end viewdidload

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
// shows the annotation with a custom image
    MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"mapAnnotation"];
    CustomAnnotation *customAnnotation = (id) annotation;
    customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green"];
    return customPinView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Grand Central Dispatch - GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) for doing this.

Try with:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
     for (NSManagedObject *object in requestResults)
     {
        CustomAnnotation *customAnnotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] init];
        customAnnotation.title = object.title;
        customAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([object.latitude doubleValue], [object.longitude doubleValue]);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [_mapView addAnnotation:customAnnotation];
        });
     }
  });
}
```

This is a nice tutorial: [GCD and threading](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial)

Comment: @LucioFonseca: this is worked for the OP, that's why he accepted it. Your's situation will be something different, find that before blaming.

Answer (score 2):

Even better & simpler, check out `-[MKMapView addAnnotations:]` to bulk add without the recalculation overhead of each individual annotation.