# Not calling MKMapView delegate (mapView:ViewForAnnotation)

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I suppose that it's going to be a silly thing but I don't know how to solve it.

First I have to say that my trouble it is because that work sometimes.

I have a main controller which some categories, then touching buttons you can open other view controllers, in this view controllers there are a custom view which contains an mkmapview with annotations.

My problem is that in some categories it deploy the annotations and in the other ones it doesn't.

When it doesn't you can check that the annotations are inside of the MKMapView but it didn't call mapView:ViewForAnnotation until you interact with the map another time.

I will show some code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    CGRect mapFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

    mapViewDefault = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:mapFrame];
    mapViewDefault.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"Eres delegado!");
    CLLocationCoordinate2D initialLocationCoordinate = [DataManager dataManager].centerCoordinate;
    [mapViewDefault setCenterCoordinate:initialLocationCoordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(initialLocationCoordinate, 3000, 3000);
    [mapViewDefault setRegion:viewRegion];
    [mapViewDefault setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [mapViewDefault setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [mapViewDefault setZoomEnabled:NO];
    if(TAPIsiOS7()){
        [mapViewDefault setRotateEnabled:NO];
    }
    [self addSubview:mapViewDefault];
}
return self;
}

- (void)addListOfPointsWithNumber:(NSArray*)arrayPoints {
NSLog(@"Añadimos anotación al array anotaciones");
[mapViewDefault removeAnnotations:mapViewDefault.annotations];
for (Place *place in arrayPoints) {
    if(![place.coordinate isEqualToString:@"0 0"]){
        Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
        annotation.coordinate = place.lCoordinate;
        annotation.number = place.number;
        annotation.place = place;
        [mapViewDefault addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

if([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]]){
    NSLog(@"Añadimos anotación al mapa");
    Annotation *annotationMap = (Annotation *)annotation;

    NSString *identifier = @"Pin";

    UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin.png"];

    MKAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    pinView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, pinImage.size.width, pinImage.size.height);


    if (annotationMap.number>0) {
        pinImage = [self imageWithView:pinImage andNumber:annotationMap.number];
    }
    pinView.image = pinImage;
    pinView.annotation = annotationMap;

    return pinView;
}
}
```

And 3 images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm pretty sure that this code works great (because I can see that in other categories) and it has to be something with execution times.

If somebody has an idea about what is happening it should be nice.

Thank you all!

Comment: Is addListOfPointsWithNumber called in a background thread?  If so, try doing the add on the main thread.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537949/how-to-add-annotations-to-mkmapview-asyncronously and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1995254/467105.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be returning *something* in all cases in your `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`, whereas you are currently only returning for certain types of annotations. At least return `nil` and see if that helps -- maybe the warning on this method is preventing some sort of runtime use (though that's a bit of a stretch).